# How to make range-slider in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I want to use range-slider to compare two values.

I found a normal slider. I couldn't find good an NPM package for this*

**This is what I want exactly:**

> npm install --save react-native-range-slider

**Link :**
[range-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-range-slider)

*Unfortunately Android doesn't support this :(  any suggestion about this  ?*

Answer (score 0):

use this https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider  it has . Options to customize track, touch area and provide customer markers and callbacks for touch events.

Comment: try to run this package example https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider/tree/master/examples/Basic